# get events from database and placing on calendar view (android)

Tags: android, mysql, calendar

I have a calendar program in my android app. Now I need to get events stored in an online `Mysql` database and  place them on the calendar. Now I have a `php` file that create a `json` object. And this `JSON` object shows all the events coming from database

**Calendar.php**

```
<?php
include 'DatabaseConfig.php';

// Create connection
//$conn = new mysqli($HostName, $HostUser, $HostPass, $DatabaseName);
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id2553265_admin", "admin", "id2553265_mobile_app");
if ($conn->connect_error) {

 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM calendar";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows >0) {


 while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

 $tem = $row;

 $json = json_encode($tem);


 }

} else {
 echo "No Results Found.";
}
 echo $json;
$conn->close();
?>
```

In this code I insert **1496134800000L** to highlight the date of **2017-05-30**. And now I have the java code that highlight and color them blue with a specific date.

```
@Override

  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar, container, false);
        //calendar setup
        compactCalendar = (CompactCalendarView) view.findViewById(R.id.comCalendarView);
        compactCalendar.setUseThreeLetterAbbreviation(true);
        calendarMonth = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.calMonth);



        Event may30 = new Event(Color.BLUE, **1496134800000L**, "test");
        compactCalendar.addEvent(may30);

        Event aug17 = new Event(Color.BLUE, 1502960400000L, "test");
        compactCalendar.addEvent(aug17);


        compactCalendar.setListener(new CompactCalendarView.CompactCalendarViewListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDayClick(Date dateClicked){
                if (dateFormatDay.format(dateClicked).toString().compareTo("**2017-05-30**") == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(CalendarFragment.this.getContext(), "There is an event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ListMay07.class);
                    i.putExtra("Date", "Sample date");
                    startActivity(i);

                }else  if (dateFormatDay.format(dateClicked).toString().compareTo("2017-08-17") == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(CalendarFragment.this.getContext(), "There is an event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ListAug17.class);
                    i.putExtra("Date", "Sample date");
                    startActivity(i);

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(CalendarFragment.this.getContext(), "No Event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onMonthScroll(Date firstDayOfNewMonth) {
                calendarMonth.setText(dateFormatMonth.format(firstDayOfNewMonth));
            }



        });
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;

    }
```

My main problem is how to get the data from the database and insert it in my java code so that all of the events will be enter in the database not in the actual code.

[image]

I want to do that by using the `JSON` object but I don't know how.

```
[{  
   "ID":"1",
   "Epoch_Time":"1496134800000L",
   "Date":"2017-05-30"   ‌​,
   "Description":"Cama‌​raderie Day"
},
{  
   "ID":"2",
   "Epoch_Time":"1502960400000L",
   "Date":"2017-0‌​8-17",
   "Description":‌​"Sample Date"
}]
```

Comment: The problem which you have mentioned "My main problem is how to get the data from the database and insert it in my java code so that all of the events will be enter in the database not in the actual code."is not very clear

Comment: I want to pull the data from the database which is the 1496134800000L and 2017-05-30 and placed it in the code so it will be dynamic not hard coded @SaranSankaran

Comment: So the JSON response which you are getting from the server can be parsed to get all the dates in them and then add them to the calendar using loop.

Comment: Yes exactly. But I am having a hard time using it in my java code. Now I have here my code where I put my json object into string

Comment: Can you post your JSON response which you are getting?

Comment: [link](https://github.com/kimpascual/Mobile_171017)

Comment: [{"ID":"1","Epoch_Time":"1496134800000L","Date":"2017-05-30","Description":"Camaraderie Day"},{"ID":"2","Epoch_Time":"1502960400000L","Date":"2017-08-17","Description":"Sample Date"}] this is the sample json

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161585/discussion-between-m-pascual-and-saran-sankaran).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a POJO for the data contained in the JSON.

```
public class Event{
   long id;
   long epochTime;
   String date;
   String  desc;

  public Event (long id, long epochTime, String date, String  desc){
      this.id = id;
      this.epochTime = epochTime;
      this.date = date;
      this.desc = desc;
  }
}
```

Then you can parse the JSON and the store it in the POJO

```
String myJsonResponse // will contain the json response from the server

try {
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(myJsonResponse);

    List<Event> events = new ArrayList<>(array.length());

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject object = (JSONObject) array.get(1);
        long id = Long.parseLong(object.getString("ID"));
        long epoctTime = Long.parseLong(object.getString("Epoch_Time"));
        String date = object.getString("Date");
        String description = object.getString("Description");

        Event event = new Event(id, epoctTime, date, description);
        events.add(event);

    }
} catch (JSONException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then you can use the event list to do whatever you want.